# increase memory_limit doesn't work in PHP Container in Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm using a container in Docker to host my Laravel app and this container is connected to another container using Nginx to host it. I'm trying to import a SQL file into my Laravel app with a seeder that's like this

```
$path = public_path('sql/2022_11_16_import_table.sql');
        $sql = file_get_contents($path);
        DB::unprepared($sql);
```

However, it displayed the error

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 186885432 bytes)
> at /var/www/database/seeds/SqlFileSeeder.php:16

I have figured this is due to my memory_limit in php.ini is being 128M so I went ahead and changed it by changing the php.ini-development and php.ini-production file inside the PHP container and then restart the whole container and the Nginx container. However, when I tried

```
php -ini
```

again the memory_limit is still 128M=>128M despite both the php.ini file has been changed. I have also tried ini_set('memory_limit','200M'); but it still seems to have no effect.

Comment: PHP only reads the php.ini file , the other 2 files (php.ini-development and php.ini-production) are provided as boilerplate to base your own php.ini so won't affect anything when changed.

Comment: Why not use a MySQL shell for this, if the file is too large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php.ini-production file will not read. PHP initialization work with `php.ini` files, which are end `.ini` extension. You can add `volume` in `Docker` for main `php.ini` files like that:

```
volumes:
   - 'configs/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
```

Content of php.ini

```ini
 memory_limit = 200M
```

If you will do it manually after `docker compose up`, then you will need to run some commands:

Enter to `Docker` container

```
docker compose -it my_container_name bash
```

Restart `PHP-fpm` and `Nginx` services

```
service php-fpm restart

service nginx reload
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a command at the end of your docker file to copy the `php.ini-production` or `php.ini-development` to `/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`.

Something like this:

```
RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini && \
        sed -i -e "s/^ *memory_limit.*/memory_limit = 4G/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I have used php.ini based on the 2 files and after reloading nginx it worked as intended. Alternatively I also tried
`ini_set` right before

```
$path = public_path('sql/2022_11_16_import_table.sql');
        $sql = file_get_contents($path);
        DB::unprepared($sql);
```

and it also did the job. Previously I ini_set in another file but after further reading I hace come to realized it just set for the current working file and not globally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this reply to help people still having issues even after updating the php.ini file.

My case was a little mixed and some how worked.

I had a docker php:fpm-7.3 docker container having php-development.ini and php-production.ini file.

I tried `cat php-production > php.ini`
And set the `memory_limit=256M`

But even that didn't work for me.

I also had a config.php file in my code where I had ini-set other variables. So I simply added another line. `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`

I'm writing this so people can use it if this works. Plus, would be grateful if someone would explain to me how php worked here?

Answer (score -1):

It's work for me:

1. enter inside conteiner with php
2. cd /usr/local/etc/php
3. echo 'memory_limit = 512M' >> php.ini

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it